# How can I extract a weekday from a timestamp in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a small table called timestamps with the only variable ts in it:

```
ts
1541990258796
1541990258312
1541990258367
<...>
```

Based on ts values of timestamps table, I want to create a factTime table where I extract hour, day and weekday from those ts values. My current query is that and it works.

```
time_table_insert = (
    """
    INSERT INTO factTime (start_time, hour, day_of_month, weekday)
    SELECT DISTINCT ts AS start_time,
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM start_time) AS hour,
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_time) AS day_of_month,
        EXTRACT(DOW FROM start_time) AS weekday
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ts,'1970-01-01'::date + ts/1000 * interval '1 second' as start_time FROM timestamps);
""")
```

Now I insert a weekday expressed in number with DOW. Is there a way to extract its actual name? How should I change my query to get the actual weekday, i.e. Monday, Friday, etc.

Comment: `to_char`  with `DAY` or `day`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
to_char('1970-01-01'::date + 1541990258312/1000 * interval '1 second', 'day')
```

I used `'1970-01-01'::date + 1541990258312/1000 * interval '1 second'` from your code - the way you get **start_time**.

Use `to_char` function with 'day' parameter.
You can also use other day parameters:

> DAY   full upper case day name (blank-padded to 9 chars)
>
> Day   full capitalized day name (blank-padded to 9 chars)
>
> day   full lower case day name (blank-padded to 9 chars)

Here you can see results of all three way's: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1a7077ce4fe4d9d848157be35d28d454)

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I've indeed never accepted answers. Good to know for the future :)

Comment: @LinaLinutina You are welcome. Happy to help. My answer give you a day name as you asked for right ? Not correrct ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a timestamp using date arithmetic and then use `extract()`:

```
select extract(dow from '1970-01-01'::timestamp + ts * interval '1 millisecond')
```

Use `to_char()` if you actually want the abbreviation rather than a number.